Como introduzco la clave del superusuario
Quiero crear un supersuario con el comando python manage.py createsuperuser en django. Me pide el nombre de usuario, el email y la contraseña pero esta ultima no me teclea nada, la consola no me deja escribir nada en la misma

no te muestra nada, pero si está recibiendo tu contraseña. Dale enter después de ingresar y te la va a aceptar.
